# How to fix an existing npm package to use in my project

Tags: react-native, npm

I am developing a React Native App and have been benefitting from lots of different npm packages for RN.

But for some of the packages, I would like to undergo minor fixes just in order to customize for my own project.

I have done so and fixed the code previously inside the node_modules directory. But this seems to be a stupid way of solving things, because you often have to reinstall many of the packages and the custom code I've written would just be gone.

How can I fix an existing package and use it in my own project? Do I have to fork the repository and adjust the code, then publish it myself as another new npm package?

Comment: Yes. Or submit a pull request to the original project and wait for it to get merged and published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either submit a PR and wait for a newer version to be release else Fork and modify the package on github. Then simply include your git project as a dependencies to package.json. Kindly refer to [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls) for the syntax.

Sample:

```
"dependencies": {
  "express": "expressjs/express",
  "module": "user/repo#feature\/branch"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution fork it from GitHub and make your changes. then you can add npm module using this command

```
npm install https://github.com/<username>/<repository>/master
```